# mongodb - Aggregate data between time range 10pm - 8am for each day for last n days

Tags: mongodb, timestamp, aggregation

My mongodb has some hourly report data, which has data for each hour. Now we want to aggregate data to get average by hour for each n number of days.

If we try to aggregate average with time range 00 AM to 23:59 PM a day Example: Day_1 01 AM to Day_1 23:59 PM we are getting expected result.

But problem lies when trying to aggregate average with time range between two different days. Example: From Day_1 10 PM to Day_2 08 AM.

We are looking for a solution, which considers days_2 data as day_1 and caluclate average for both days for last n days.

Following is our sample data as logic we following.
Sample data:

```
{
    "TimeStamp" : ISODate("2017-08-17T22:00:00.000Z"),
    "A" : 100.0,
    "B" : 10.0,
    "C" : 30.0,
    "D" : 50.0
}
{
    "TimeStamp" : ISODate("2017-08-17T23:00:00.000"),
    "A" : 100.0,
    "B" : 10.0,
    "C" : 20.0,
    "D" : 30.0
}
{
    "TimeStamp" : ISODate("2017-08-18T06:00:00.000Z"),
    "A" : 100.0,
    "B" : 40.0,
    "C" : 10.0,
    "D" : 40.0
}
{
    "TimeStamp" : ISODate("2017-08-18T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "A" : 100.0,
    "B" : 50.0,
    "C" : 10.0,
    "D" : 50.0
}

{
    "TimeStamp" : ISODate("2017-09-01T22:00:00.000Z"),
    "A" : 100.0,
    "B" : 20.0,
    "C" : 10.0,
    "D" : 50.0
}

{
    "TimeStamp" : ISODate("2017-09-02T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "A" : 100.0,
    "B" : 60.0,
    "C" : 10.0,
    "D" : 70.0
}
```

Query is :
Following query is working fine for time range between 00AM to 23:59PM (same date)

```
 db.getCollection('prod_amount').aggregate( [ 
    { $project: {
        A: 1,        
        TimeStamp: 1, 
        dateField: {'$dateToString': {format: '%Y-%m-%d', date: '$TimeStamp'}},
        minutes: { $add: [
            { $multiply: [ { $hour: '$TimeStamp' }, 60 ] }, 
            { $minute: '$TimeStamp' } 
        ] } 
    } },
    { $match: {"TimeStamp":{$gte:new Date("2017-08-17"),$lte:new Date("2017-09-01")}, 'minutes' : { $gte : 10 * 60, $lte : 20 * 60 } } },
    { $group: {"_id":{dateField: '$dateField'}, Prod : {"$avg":"$A"}}}
])
```

Looking help in building query for time range between two different days. Example: From Day_1 10 PM to Day_2 08 AM.